# Divide $m$ objects with different weight in $n$ groups in order so difference in groupweight is minimal

Tags: algorithms

I'm trying to divide $m$ elements into $n$ groups. Each of the $m$ elements has its own weight. Those elements should be divided into $n$ groups, where following conditions should be met:

- groups contain elements **in the same order** as the given list of elements
- The difference in group weight should be minimal
- groups consist of elements wich follow eachother, without skipping any. as in A and C in one group without B would be invalid. B should be in that group aswell

An example:

elements:

- A: weight = 100
- B: weight = 200
- C: weight = 150
- D: weight = 75

number of groups: 3
should be grouped as: A, B, CD

Comment: What do you mean by difference in group weight?

Comment: Are you simply trying to minimize the maximum group weight? I'm assuming group weight means the sum of all weights in  certain group.

Comment: your assumption is correct

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved in pseudo-polynomial time using dynamic programming or memoization:

Let $f(W, n)$, where $W = (w_1, ..., w_m)$, be the solution to the problem for weights in $W$ and $n$ groups, then:

$\displaystyle f(W, n) = \min_{k \leq m} \max(S_k, f((w_{k+1}, ..., w_m), n-1))$

where $S_k$ is the sum of the first $k$ weights.

That is, try forming the first group by choosing the first $k$ weights, and recursively solve the problem for the remaining weights and $n-1$ groups.

Comment: Note that this may not produce an optimal grouping.

Comment: @MJD It should be if groups are required to contain elements in the same  order as given in the list...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is [NP-Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard) and there has a simple reduction from the [partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem)

In fact, if we assume that there are only $2$ groups, then this is exactly the partition problem. So, we can reduce the partition problem to a special instance of this problem with only 2 groups. Since the partition problem is known to be NP-Hard, this problem is also hard.

However, you can solve it by dynamic programming in pseudo-polynomial time as follows.

Let's define $P(i,j)$ to be the optimum way to partition the sequence of weights into $j$ groups starting from position $i$ such that the maximum sum in each group is minimum. And $a_i$ as the $i$th element of the list of weights given. And we want to partition them into $g$ groups.

Then $P(i,j)$ can be obtained as follows:

$$P(i,j)=\min\limits_{1\le m\le i}^{}(\max(\sum\limits_{p=i}^{m}a_p,P(m+1,j-1)))$$

You can find more details [here](http://www8.cs.umu.se/kurser/TDBA77/VT06/algorithms/BOOK/BOOK2/NODE45.HTM) and [here](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/video-lectures/2007/lecture18.pdf) (pages 9-16)

Comment: I originally wrote about the partition problem, but OP's problem is actually harder than the partition problem. There is a pseudo-polynomial-time algorithm for partitioning the weights into to groups, explained by dani_s elsewhere in this thread, but none is known for partitioning the weights into more than two groups.

Comment: Now it transpires that OP's problem is actually much easier than the partition problem, because of the requirement that the numbers are ordered and must be divided into contiguous subsequences.

Comment: it's still NP-Hard, even with these additional assumptions.

Comment: It certainly isn't; a brute-force algorithm runs in $O(n^k)$, where $k$, the desired number of groups, is a constant.

Comment: Well, that's if you make the assumption that $k$ is a constant. But $O(n^k)$ is still not polynomial in the input size.

Comment: Okay, but it's pseudo-polynomial, which the $k$-partition problem is not, except when $k=2$.